# How to wire a three phase machine to a single phase plug?

Tags: electrical, wiring

The machine has five wires, three of which are live. I want to wire into a single phase supply using a three prong plug.

It powers a boiler and water pump (for an espresso machine: 220-240V, 50/60Hz, 0.190Mpa/0.65Mpa, 3000W).

The advice I received was to twist the three live wires together and wire them all to the one live prong.

The problem I have is that the the three together is to thick. Is there a way to do this?

---

Solution: what I found was a connector (not sure what it's called) big enough to take the three wires together with a single wire coming out the other side. Someone else suggested 'wrapping' two of the wires around the third.

Comment: Unless the machine has a wiring diagram so that you can change it from three phase to single phase this is not going to happen.

Comment: Fascinated by the idea that an espresso machine is set up to run on 3 phase power... maybe you can provide pics/ model number if not an actual wiring diagram.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate it's presumably of European origin, given the specs, and 3-phase is more widely distributed there, AIUII. I do wonder if the Wattage is really 3100, not 310, which seems rather low.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- I learn something new here every day. And agreed that a 310W boiler would be pretty sad.

Comment: @Ecnerwal:  Is three phase more common in Europe than the U.S.?  I don't think I have seen anything but large European industrial installations with 3 phrase.  In the U.S., 3 phase is in most residential neighborhoods and in the largest houses and medium-plus sized businesses.

Comment: It is European, a Promac Green Compact Semi-automatic from Italy. Yes, 3000 Watts - not sure what the other number is then. I opened it up but could see nothing useful. Also found a manual on-line that didn't make much sense to me on this particular point. I eventually spoke with a technician with experience installing these machines who confirmed the original advise and told me how to combine the wires. So that's what I did, and it's running, seemingly without a problem.

Comment: @Stephen, that's all well and good, but what about the amperage? Did anyone, YOU, consider that you may be upping the amperage over what the circuit is designed for? What amperage and voltage is the circuit you connected it to? Also, now that we know a name and model, two weeks later, it seems this machine is not 3-phase as you stated in the original title.

Answer (score 8):

You can't just fix this with wiring.

You either need to get 3 phase supplied to your location and wired to the device, or you need a phase converter, such as what these guys sell:

http://www.northamericaphaseconverters.com

A possible alternative might be to use a VFD, such as this one:

[http://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Drives/GS2_%28115_-z-*230*-z-*460*-z-_575_VAC_V-z-Hz_Control%29/GS2_Drive_Units_%28115_-z-*230*-z-*460*-z-_575_VAC%29/GS2-11P0](http://www.automationdirect.com/adc/Shopping/Catalog/Drives/GS2_%28115_-z-_230_-z-_460_-z-_575_VAC_V-z-Hz_Control%29/GS2_Drive_Units_%28115_-z-_230_-z-_460_-z-_575_VAC%29/GS2-11P0)

In either case, I would seek advice from the device manufacture's tech lines to confirm it's suitable for your application. These devices are generally expected to be connected to a motor, and you have a heater - that is an electrically significant difference.

Also note that I doubt the 3 phase is just powering the boiler. I don't know coffee, really, but I thought high-end espresso machines were pump driven - the pump will be 3 phase too I suspect.

Comment: There may also be electronics that run off only one of the legs at 120V.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Pump also, yes. A phase converter would be very expensive for me so I was pleased to find out that combining the three wires is common practice here - I've now down that and it's working.

Comment: Ok, well I'd say you got "lucky" - again I don't know espresso machines, and perhaps they are generally designed in a way that means they'll work when you rewire them in that way, however as a general rule 3 phase equipment will not work using this approach.

Answer (score 5):

Lacking a model number to look up, I would try opening the device near the power cord and see if there is a jumper assembly or instructions for converting to other voltages and phase supplies.

Comment: This is a poor course of action that would likely result in injury or destruction of the equipment. Do not attempt.

Comment: I upvote WallyK.  Its a good idea.   Lots of machines have voltage conversion methods.

Comment: +1 to wallyk -- this is the land of DIY, and a prudent individual would unplug the machine and use appropriate caution, possibly including the use of insulated screwdrivers. I've owned (and entirely stripped/rebuilt) a one group commercial espresso maker, and I can assure you that stored high voltage electronics is not one of that machine's attributes. Power goes mainly to the boiler, a little to the pump, and a bit to the brain if it does electronic dosing.

Comment: @cathode -- many machines are designed for this -- there will be a marked jumper or switch for the job.

Comment: Voltage conversion, yes. NOT phase conversion by simple rewiring.

Comment: @cathode:  Since the three phase appears to be for heating elements and not a motor, this is a moot issue.

Answer (score 4):

Having recently purchased and rewired from three phase to single phase on a [Wega Pegaso coffee machine](https://espresso-machines.nu/wega-pegaso-espresso-machine).
[image]
This is what I found and did successfully.
Firstly most commercial coffee machines are mono-phase, and can be wired 3 or single phase.
The 3 phase has 3 individual lives all acting independently, by joining these together they act as one. One supplies the power the other 2 cancel each other out.
You should not risk wiring to a 13amp plug but install a dedicated 20amp supply from your mainboard to a new socket near your machine.
I have a 2 group machine, with a 3.7kw boiler, stating 400 volts (three phase).
I have had no problems making 4 coffees at a time and all pressure etc are perfect.
Hope this helps as it took me nearly a day of searching before I finally was confident to tackle the wiring.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.